# How to show a list of text as marquee one by one

Tags: javascript, html, css, marquee

I have a list of text's which contains 5 strings. I want to show them each one by one in marquee.

Refer the latest news div of this page http://returntrucks.in/

Comment: Please someone help me out on this.

Comment: we would love to know what you have tried so far! we love to see code ;)

Comment: and i don't think you will require javascript for this, css is enough